# Wait...are types NUMBER and VARCHAR2 no longer allowed in sqlldr?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-loader

Bizarre syntax error:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE z.dat
INTO TABLE table1
REPLACE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(

    COL1 NUMBER(10), 
    COL2  
)
```

Is yielding:

```
Expecting "," or ")", found "NUMBER".
        COL1 NUMBER(10),
      ^
```

Works with type DECIMAL. Backend - Oracle12c. OS - RHEL.
Did I miss the memo?

SQL*Loader: Release 12.2.0.1.0

Even more: would not allow type VARCHAR2, but VARCHAR is ok. Has anyone encountered this behavior/bug?

This comes through:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'z.dat'
INTO TABLE table1
(
col1 VARCHAR(10), 
col2 INTEGER
)
```

This - does not:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'z.dat'
INTO TABLE table1
(
col1 VARCHAR2(10), 
col2 INTEGER
)
```

SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 7.
Expecting valid column specification, "," or ")", found "VARCHAR2".
col1 VARCHAR2(10),
      ^

The funkiest fact is that I was even using an example from Oracle's docs (albeit 10g), and it still won't get through.

Comment: SQL*Loader has always had its own types. I’d be interested to see the document that says otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Did you **ever** manage to use those datatypes?

Generally, we've used

- `INTEGER EXTERNAL` for numbers
- `CHAR` for strings

Besides, that's what documentation in *SQL Loader Field List Reference* suggests; have a look at list of available datatypes ((https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-DB309002-461D-42F7-8C94-727B32FA8B85) and you'll see that there are no `NUMBER` nor `VARCHAR2` there.

It seems you misinterpreted reality :)